# Redirect output audio to input

Tags: javascript, webrtc, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I've implemented a WebRTC app that connects customers and clients; it's working so smooth but now I need to play an audio with legal clauses that should be heard by customers and they need to say something like `I agree`.

I'm searching on many forums on how is possible to redirect output to input (microphone) and I've reached a solution like:

- Get the input source;
- Convert my audio file to a buffer or something similar;
- Send this "buffer" to input source.

Is it viable?

The code should look like:

```
navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, 
    function(stream){
        //what should I do here? Already have the mp3 buffer here
    },
    function(err){
        console.log('Cagou demais', err)
    }
)
```

I'm totally stuck on how implement it. Many topics that I found are from 2013.

Comment: `navigator.getUserMedia` is deprecated. Use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Comment: "redirect output to input", that doesn't make any sense.  Don't you mean you want to record the input?

Comment: @Brad No. I want that the MP3 should be listened by customer. Customer can't hear the audio file when I play it on my computer. If i try to record, MP3 will be listened by customer?

Comment: You simply want to play an audio file?  Just use an `<audio>` tag.  What's all this WebRTC stuff for?

Comment: Are you trying to play an audio file so that a *remote person* on a WebRTC call can hear it?

Comment: Yes! I'm trying to play an audio file so a remote person on a WebRTC call should hear it and say "i agree". Is it possible?

Comment: @Brad any help?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than sending the microphone directly in your MediaStream to the remote, you need to use the Web Audio API to create an audio context and then send its output to the remote.

Basically, create an audio context, and call `audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(microphoneStream)`.

Next, create a MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode via `audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination()`.  Connect your microphone and any other nodes you want to output, such as a buffer node for your recording.

When you make your WebRTC call, instantiate a new MediaStream using the tracks from the webcam, and the `destinationNode.stream`.  Send the new resulting stream in your call, and it will have everything combined.

Comment: Man, this sounds great. Will it work if the javascripts apps are in same page but different iframes?

Comment: @placplacboom Specifics matter here, so either post a new question with details on that, or just try it out and see for yourself.  I've successfully shared streams between frames/windows before, but I had to pass the blob URL to do it.